# How to attach multiple security groups to RDS and Elasticache Redis with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to attach multiple security groups to my RDS and Elasticache instances, I somehow didn't manage to do it and I didn't quite understand why,

Basically, I'm trying to combine two security group id outputs from two different places and assign them to my RDS and Elasticache.

But it keeps giving the error below,
I tried to do it with concat(), flatten(),toset() and tolist() functions but it doesn't help. Terraform documentation says multiple security groups can be given as a list but I couldn't make it work.

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on modules/aws/elasticache-redis/main.tf line 26, in resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "elasticache-redis":
  26:   security_group_ids   = [var.security_group_ids]
    |----------------
    | var.security_group_ids is tuple with 2 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "security_group_ids": element 0: string
required.


Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on modules/aws/rds-mysql/main.tf line 26, in resource "aws_db_instance" "rds-mysql":
  26:   vpc_security_group_ids          = [var.security_group]
    |----------------
    | var.security_group is tuple with 2 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "vpc_security_group_ids": element 0: string
required.
```

Here my files,

main.tf

```
module "example-module" {
  source = "./modules/example-module"

  environment                          = var.environment
  private_subnet_ids                   = module.vpc.private_subnet_ids
  rds_mysql_security_group             = [module.common-rds-mysql-security-group.security_group_id, module.security-group.rds-mysql-security-group]
  elasticache_redis_security_group_ids = [module.common-elasticache-redis-security-group.security_group_id, module.security-group.elasticache-redis-security-group]
  aws_sns_topic_arn                    = module.sns-system-notification-topic.topic_arn
 

  depends_on = [module.vpc, module.sns-system-notification-topic]
}
```

my example-module module;

```
module "rds-mysql" {
  source = "../../aws/rds-mysql"

  identifier = "${var.environment}-${var.svc_name}"

  engine_version    = var.rds_mysql_engine_version
  instance_class    = var.rds_mysql_instance_class
  allocated_storage = var.rds_mysql_allocated_storage
  storage_type      = var.rds_mysql_storage_type

  name     = var.rds_mysql_name
  username = var.rds_mysql_username
  password = var.rds_mysql_password
  port     = var.rds_mysql_port

  parameter_group_name = var.rds_mysql_parameter_group_name
  security_group       = var.rds_mysql_security_group

  private_subnet_ids       = var.private_subnet_ids
  subnet_group_name        = "${var.environment}-${var.svc_name}-rds-mysql-subnet-group"
  subnet_group_description = "${var.environment}-${var.svc_name}-rds-mysql-subnet-group"

  auto_minor_version_upgrade      = var.rds_mysql_auto_minor_version_upgrade
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = var.rds_mysql_enabled_log_types
  publicly_accessible             = var.rds_mysql_publicly_accessible
  skip_final_snapshot             = var.rds_mysql_skip_final_snapshot
  maintenance_window              = var.rds_mysql_maintenance_window
  backup_retention_period         = var.rds_mysql_backup_retention_period
  backup_window                   = var.rds_mysql_backup_window
  copy_tags_to_snapshot           = var.rds_mysql_copy_tags_to_snapshot
  deletion_protection             = var.rds_mysql_deletion_protection
  multi_az                        = var.rds_mysql_multi_az
  enable_slave                    = var.rds_mysql_enable_slave
  slave_count                     = var.rds_mysql_slave_count

  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.environment}-${var.svc_name}"
    Name        = "${var.environment}-${var.svc_name}-rds-mysql"
  }
}

module "elasticache-redis" {
  source = "../../aws/elasticache-redis"

  replication_group_id          = "${var.environment}-${var.svc_name}"
  replication_group_description = "${var.environment}-${var.svc_name}"

  engine_version = var.elasticache_redis_engine_version
  port           = var.elasticache_redis_port

  number_cache_clusters = var.elasticache_redis_number_cache_clusters
  node_type             = var.elasticache_redis_node_type

  notification_topic_arn = var.elasticache_event_alerts_topic_arn

  parameter_group_name = var.elasticache_redis_parameter_group_name
  security_group_ids   = var.elasticache_redis_security_group_ids
  subnet_group_name    = "${var.environment}-${var.svc_name}-redis-subnet-group"
  private_subnet_ids   = var.private_subnet_ids

  auto_minor_version_upgrade = var.elasticache_redis_auto_minor_version_upgrade
  maintenance_window         = var.elasticache_redis_maintenance_window
  snapshot_window            = var.elasticache_redis_snapshot_window
  snapshot_retention_limit   = var.elasticache_redis_snapshot_retention_limit

  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.environment}-${var.svc_name}"
    Name        = "${var.environment}-${var.svc_name}-redis"
  }
}
```

And finally,my RDS and Elasticache Modules,

```
resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "elasticache-redis" {
  automatic_failover_enabled    = var.automatic_failover_enabled
  availability_zones            = [data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]]
  replication_group_id          = var.replication_group_id
  replication_group_description = var.replication_group_description

  engine         = var.engine
  engine_version = var.engine_version
  port           = var.port

  number_cache_clusters = var.number_cache_clusters
  node_type             = var.node_type

  notification_topic_arn = var.notification_topic_arn

  parameter_group_name = var.parameter_group_name
  security_group_ids   = [var.security_group_ids]
  subnet_group_name    = aws_elasticache_subnet_group.elasticache-redis-subnet-group.id

  auto_minor_version_upgrade = var.auto_minor_version_upgrade
  maintenance_window         = var.maintenance_window
  snapshot_window            = var.snapshot_window
  snapshot_retention_limit   = var.snapshot_retention_limit
  tags                       = var.tags

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      availability_zones
    ]
  }
}
```

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "rds-mysql" {
  identifier = var.identifier

  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
  engine            = var.engine
  engine_version    = var.engine_version
  instance_class    = var.instance_class
  allocated_storage = var.allocated_storage
  storage_type      = var.storage_type

  name     = var.name
  username = var.username
  password = var.password
  port     = var.port

  parameter_group_name            = var.parameter_group_name
  db_subnet_group_name            = aws_db_subnet_group.rds-mysql-subnet-group.id
  vpc_security_group_ids          = [var.security_group]
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = var.enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports

  auto_minor_version_upgrade = var.auto_minor_version_upgrade
  publicly_accessible        = var.publicly_accessible
  skip_final_snapshot        = var.skip_final_snapshot
  maintenance_window         = var.maintenance_window
  backup_retention_period    = var.backup_retention_period
  backup_window              = var.backup_window
  copy_tags_to_snapshot      = var.copy_tags_to_snapshot
  deletion_protection        = var.deletion_protection
  multi_az                   = var.multi_az

  apply_immediately = true

  tags = var.tags

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      availability_zone
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "rds-mysql-slave" {
  count = var.enable_slave ? var.slave_count : 0

  identifier = "${var.identifier}-${count.index + 1}"

  engine            = var.engine
  engine_version    = var.engine_version
  instance_class    = var.instance_class
  allocated_storage = var.allocated_storage
  storage_type      = var.storage_type

  name     = var.name
  username = var.username
  password = var.password
  port     = var.port

  parameter_group_name   = var.parameter_group_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_group]

  replicate_source_db = aws_db_instance.rds-mysql.identifier

  auto_minor_version_upgrade      = var.auto_minor_version_upgrade
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = var.enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports
  publicly_accessible             = var.publicly_accessible
  skip_final_snapshot             = var.skip_final_snapshot
  maintenance_window              = var.maintenance_window
  backup_retention_period         = var.backup_retention_period
  backup_window                   = var.backup_window
  copy_tags_to_snapshot           = var.copy_tags_to_snapshot
  deletion_protection             = var.deletion_protection
  multi_az                        = var.multi_az

  tags = var.tags
}
```

My security group outputs ;

```
RDS 1 :
output "rds-mysql-security-group" {
    value = aws_security_group.rds-mysql-security-group.id
}
Elasticache 1 :
output "elasticache-redis-security-group" {
    value = aws_security_group.elasticache-redis-security-group.id
}
RDS 2 :
output "security_group_id" {
    value = module.rds-mysql-security-group.security_group_id
}
Elasticache 2 :
output "security_group_id" {
    value = module.elasticache-redis-security-group.security_group_id
}
```

The outputs above should combine as one list in the main.tf and be inherited by child module.

Any help will be highly appreciated,
Thank you very much.

Comment: What exactly is `var.security_group_ids`?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I have three layers in my Terraform, one is main.tf, one is service modules and the last one aws resource modules, each service part is calling it's related aws modules to create service related resources. so var.security_group_ids is inherited from the main.tf as 
`rds_mysql_security_group             = [module.common-rds-mysql-security-group.security_group_id, module.security-group.rds-mysql-security-group]`, is passed through the service module to reach aws module, so as I said, the security groups are inherited to my RDS and Elasticache modules from the root main.tf

Comment: I think it should be ` security_group_ids   = var.security_group_ids`

Comment: You think I should remove the brackets?

Comment: @Marcin when I remove the brackets, the error is evolving to 
`var.security_group_ids is "sg-xxx"
Inappropriate value for attribute "security_group_ids": set of string
required.`

Comment: What is the definition of `var.security_group_ids`?

Comment: Hey @Marcin, it's 
`[module.common-elasticache-redis-security-group.security_group_id, module.security-group.elasticache-redis-security-group]`
as I said, it's inherited from main.tf, it's combination of two security groups.

Comment: I mean, what is your variables.tf file.

Comment: It's empty like this
`variable "security_group_ids" {}`
it's taking its value from other modules.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, any luck ?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Comment: @Marcin, Sorry for late response, I was taking care of other tasks. Yes I understood the problem about 30 mins ago :) There are other databases that using the same module without brackets was returning the error :) I'm gonna approve your answer because it's true and working with that way. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know and glad it worked out:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, in your `rds-mysql`, `rds-mysql-slave` and and `elasticache-redis` it should be:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "elasticache-redis" {
  #...
  security_group_ids   = var.security_group_ids
  #...
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "rds-mysql" {
  #... 
  vpc_security_group_ids          = var.security_group
  #...  
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "rds-mysql-slave" {
  #...
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.security_group
  #...  
}
```

This is because `var.security_group` and `var.security_group_ids` are already lists.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding again, but as I said earlier, when I remove the brackets, error is transforming to `var.security_group_ids is "sg-xxx" Inappropriate value for attribute "security_group_ids": set of string required.`

Comment: @OguzhanAygun If you get such error, then your code that you posted is probably not the real code of yours. `var.security_group_ids`, based on your code, should be `[module.common-elasticache-redis-security-group.security_group_id, module.security-group.elasticache-redis-security-group]`.

Comment: Why whould I post the files that are not mine as my files and ask help? Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: @OguzhanAygun No problem, but it happens all the time. Ppl keep modifying their programs after posting the question. Then later, when they test answers given, they have different code or variables than when they made the question. Thus, I don't see how you would get an error that `var.security_group_ids` is a string based on your code in the question.